# Loading SKTexutre Crash mutated while being enumerated

Tags: ios, sktexture

I'm having problems with the following code, which loads an SKTexture by calling its size. The code crashes at random about 1 out of every 100 runs at the line where size is called. There are some other SKTexture methods for pre-loading the images but they also cause a crash even more frequently! I use TextureAtlases and to prevent the crash all of my SKTexure loads happen through this method.

```
/* add image to dictionary thread-safe */
-(SKTexture*) getThreadSafeDictionaryContainImageOtherwiseLoadAndReturn:(NSString*) imageToLoad andForceLoad:(BOOL) forceLoad{

    // to control the enviroment where the image dictionary is modified, go ahead and lock it down with an NSLock
    [self.dictionaryModificationLock lock];

    SKTexture *toReturn = nil;
    CGSize size = CGSizeZero;

    // first, ignore duplicate loads by looking for the image in an NSDictionary called "allImages"
    if ((toReturn = [self.allImages objectForKey:imageToLoad])){
        // have the image to return already loaded

    }else{
        // grab the SKTexture and force it to load by requesting it's size
        SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:imageToLoad];
        if (forceLoad)
            size = texture.size; // crashes here!

        [self.allImages setObject:texture forKey:imageToLoad];
        toReturn = texture;
    }

    [self.dictionaryModificationLock unlock]; // unlock the NSLock
    return toReturn;
}
```

Here's what the crash report looks like:

```
Fatal Exception: NSGenericException
*** Collection <NSConcreteMapTable: 0x1c059ff0> was mutated while being enumerated.

0   CoreFoundation  __exceptionPreprocess + 126
2   CoreFoundation  -[NSException name]
3   Foundation  -[NSConcreteMapTable countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:] + 56
4   CoreFoundation  -[__NSFastEnumerationEnumerator nextObject] + 110
5   SpriteKit   +[SKTextureAtlas(Internal) findTextureNamed:] + 284
6   SpriteKit   __26-[SKTexture loadImageData]_block_invoke + 1654
7   SpriteKit   SKSpinLockSync(int*, void () block_pointer) + 104
8   SpriteKit   -[SKTexture loadImageData] + 302
9   SpriteKit   -[SKTexture size] + 42
```

I've found some other threads saying this is a problem with SpriteKit. But I think there must be some work around. What do you guys think?

Thanks,

Garren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Its a bug**

This definitely looks like a bug in SpriteKit. You could try to preload the image first, it may end up down a separate code path. Its possible preloading will help prevent this from occurring.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH9-SW21

**Atlas**

If you aren't already, consider using a texture atlas and preloading all your assets in there.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH9-SW15

**Locking**

A side note, and I don't think this will solve your crash at all, but using @synchronized for locking is more semantic.

Instead of having an NSLock, just wrap the current lock code in an `@synchronized(self)`. If you are having contention with other parts of the code that also lock on self then you can create a separate `id textureLockObject` property.

Apple can and will optimize @synchronized code more so than using NSLocks.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW3